# Add new proposal in Eclipse for Python

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I see the proposals in Eclipse and can also set the ones which should be used in Eclipse.
But how can I add new proposals for an existing API (Python API) for the PyDev Plugin?

So when there is the method / function `getUser(...)` in the Python API I want it to appear in the proposals / add all methods, classes ... as new proposal set.

For example I want to add proposal function for jQuery and its methods to Eclipse like `.load(...)` but now just for a Python API / Framework.

Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the "Predefined Completions" in the Interpreter configuration ( there are instructions at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html )